# Turtle module: screen.update() seems to freeze up the program

Tags: python, module

I'm creating a game using the turtle module. I included in my code something like this to smooth out the animation:

```
screen.tracer(0)
```

Then I update the screen with:

```
screen.update()
```

However, when I run the code, the animation freezes. Does anyone know what's happened here?

Answer (score 0):

well it works correctly!

the screen should always be in freeze mode (because of `.tracer(0)`  method), unless it sees the `.update()` and then because of this method it refresh it state and then back to the freeze mode.

source: [tracer documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.tracer)

so basically it should update the screen once but if you want to update the screen constantly, you should put the `screen.update()` (and your entire code) in a **while loop**. here is an example:

```
from turtle import Screen
screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(0)


game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    screen.update()

    # your code

screen.exitonclick()
```